# QBO3 Matrix Filter does not sort as expected

Tags: rules, fuzzy-logic

I have two QBO matricies:

1. Matrix A has 1 input and 1 outputs,
2. Matrix B has 3 inputs and 1 outputs

When I navigate to Matrix A, I see something like this:

```
| Client | Price  | 
| ------ | ------ |
|        | 120.00 |
| A,B,C  | 100.00 |
| D,E    |  90.00 |
| F      |  95.00 |
```

when I enter E into the client filter, the Matrix sorts as I would expect, with the first row 'valid' and the others crossed out:

```
| Client | Price  | 
| ------ | ------ |
| D,E    |  90.00 |
|        | 120.00 |
| A,B,C  | 100.00 |
| F      |  95.00 |
```

Matrix B looks like this:

```
| Client    | State | Investor | Price  |
| --------- | ----- | -------- | ------ |
|           | CA    | NOT(2,3) | 100.00 |
| San Diego | CA    |          | 110.00 |
|           | FL    |          |  95.00 |
| Miami     | FL    | 3        | 105.00 |
```

When I enter 'Miami' into the Client column filter, the sorting appears like this with **all columns** crossed out:

```
| Client    | State | Investor | Price  |
| --------- | ----- | -------- | ------ |
|           | CA    | NOT(2,3) | 100.00 |
|           | FL    |          | 95.00  |
| San Diego | CA    |          | 110.00 |
| Miami     | FL    | 3        | 105.00 |
```

Why don't I see the row with Miami at the top?

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the row with Miami also requires State = 'FL', so that row is not a match. To get the Miami row to match, you must enter City = 'Miami' **and** State = 'FL'.

When the Matrix is evaluated, it calculates the following:

- for each row of the matrix

  - for each input of the matrix

    - if the row has a value that equals your input, that's a 'match'
    - if the row has a value and you provided no input, that's a 'mismatch'
    - if the row has a NOT(value) and you provided no input, that's a 'match'
- sort by

  - weight descending,
  - then by number of mismatches,
  - then by the number of matches

For the Matrix B output:

```
| Client    | State | Investor | Price  |
| --------- | ----- | -------- | ------ |
|           | CA    | NOT(2,3) | 100.00 | Mismatch = 1, Match=1
|           | FL    |          | 95.00  | Mismatch = 1, Match=0
| San Diego | CA    |          | 110.00 | Mismatch = 2, Match=1
| Miami     | FL    | 3        | 105.00 | Mismatch = 2, Match=1
```

In short:

- The 'Miami' line requires 3 inputs to match, and 2 did not, so it's at the bottom
- the first line (CA) actually matches your 'empty' input because it just cares about the Investor NOT being Investor 2 or 3 -- no investor matches this requirement!